# How do I monitor api request quotas or usage?

Tags: google-drive-api

I am familiar with the Google API Console for monitoring requests quotas, but is there an endpoint or Google API Resource that I can query for poll to get current quota usage information for an enabled API, eg, Google Drive API?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no current API endpoint to get/poll the current quota usage information. As I previously mentioned in a related SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41745491/5995040), receiving quota related errors would help you know that you are reaching your quota for the API and that is where your [error handling](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/handle-errors) will take over.

To view the quota usage, access your [developer console](https://console.developers.google.com/). And you are correct, it is viewable using the console. You can also see traffic ( number of request per seconds), and error ratio of the enabled API of your project.